# Strange error when taking gradient of TensorArray

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the code pasted below.  The 'forward' part of the code seems to work by virtue of the "assert root_emb == 1 + emb[0] * emb[1]" passing.  However, once a training step is taken (the line following the assert), a strange error appears suggesting an issue with the TensorArray written to during the wihle loop.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: TensorArray
>   TensorArray@gradients: Could not read from TensorArray index 2 because
>   it has not yet been written to.    [[Node:
>   gradients/while/TensorArrayWrite_grad/TensorArrayRead =
>   TensorArrayRead[_class=["loc:@TensorArray"], dtype=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](gradients/while/TensorArrayWrite_grad/TensorArrayGrad/TensorArrayGrad,
>   gradients/while/TensorArrayWrite_grad/TensorArrayRead/StackPop,
>   gradients/while/TensorArrayWrite_grad/TensorArrayGrad/gradient_flow)]]
>   Caused by op u'gradients/while/TensorArrayWrite_grad/TensorArrayRead',
>   defined at:   File "minimal.py", line 82, in 
>       model = TreeRNN(8, 1, 1, degree=2)   File "minimal.py", line 61, in **init**
>       self.grad = tf.gradients(self.loss, self.params)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py",
>   line 481, in gradients
>       in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_grad.py",
>   line 115, in _TensorArrayWriteGrad
>       grad = g.read(index)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py",
>   line 177, in read
>       dtype=self._dtype, name=name)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py",
>   line 781, in _tensor_array_read
>       flow_in=flow_in, dtype=dtype, name=name)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py",
>   line 694, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2154, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1154, in **init**
>       self._traceback = _extract_stack()
>
> ...which was originally created as op u'while/TensorArrayWrite',
>   defined at:   File "minimal.py", line 82, in 
>       model = TreeRNN(8, 1, 1, degree=2)   File "minimal.py", line 50, in **init**
>       loop_vars=(self.time, node_emb, tf.zeros([1])))   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py",
>   line 1681, in While
>       back_prop=back_prop, swap_memory=swap_memory, name=name)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py",
>   line 1671, in while_loop
>       result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py",
>   line 1572, in BuildLoop
>       body_result = body(*vars_for_body_with_tensor_arrays)   File "minimal.py", line 43, in _recurrence
>       new_node_emb = node_emb.write(children_and_parent[-1], parent_emb)   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py",
>   line 200, in write
>       name=name)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py",
>   line 875, in _tensor_array_write
>       value=value, flow_in=flow_in, name=name)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py",
>   line 694, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops, control_flow_ops


class TreeRNN(object):

    def __init__(self, num_emb, emb_dim, output_dim, degree=2, learning_rate=0.01):
        self.num_emb = num_emb
        self.emb_dim = emb_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.degree= degree
        self.learning_rate = tf.Variable(float(learning_rate), trainable=False)

        self.embeddings = tf.Variable(self.init_matrix([self.num_emb, self.emb_dim]))
        self.recursive_unit = self.create_recursive_unit()
        self.W_out = tf.Variable(self.init_matrix([self.output_dim, self.emb_dim]))
        self.b_out = tf.Variable(self.init_vector([self.output_dim]))

        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])  # word indices
        self.tree = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, self.degree + 1])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[self.output_dim])

        num_words, = tf.unpack(tf.shape(self.x), 1)  # also num leaves
        emb_x = tf.gather(self.embeddings, self.x)
        node_emb = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
            dtype=tf.float32, size=num_words - 1, dynamic_size=True,
            clear_after_read=False)
        node_emb = node_emb.unpack(emb_x)

        num_nodes, _ = tf.unpack(tf.shape(self.tree), 2)  # num internal nodes
        tree_traversal = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
            dtype=tf.int32, size=num_nodes)
        tree_traversal = tree_traversal.unpack(self.tree)

        def _recurrence(t, node_emb, _):
            node_info = tree_traversal.read(t)
            children_and_parent = tf.unpack(node_info, self.degree + 1)
            child_emb = []
            for i in xrange(self.degree):
                child_emb.append(node_emb.read(children_and_parent[i]))
            parent_emb = self.recursive_unit(child_emb)
            new_node_emb = node_emb.write(children_and_parent[-1], parent_emb)
            return t + 1, new_node_emb, parent_emb

        self.time = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32, name='time')
        _, _, final_emb = control_flow_ops.While(
            cond=lambda t, _1, _2: t < num_nodes,
            body=_recurrence,
            loop_vars=(self.time, node_emb, tf.zeros([1])))

        self.final_state = final_emb

        self.pred_y = self.activation(
            tf.matmul(self.W_out, tf.reshape(self.final_state, [self.emb_dim, 1]))
            + self.b_out)
        self.loss = self.loss_fn(self.y, self.pred_y)

        self.params = tf.trainable_variables()
        opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
        self.grad = tf.gradients(self.loss, self.params)
        self.updates = opt.apply_gradients(zip(self.grad, self.params))

    def init_matrix(self, shape):
        return tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)

    def init_vector(self, shape):
        return tf.zeros(shape)

    def create_recursive_unit(self):
        def unit(child_emb):  # very simple
            return 1 + child_emb[0] * child_emb[1]
        return unit

    def activation(self, inp):
        return tf.sigmoid(inp)

    def loss_fn(self, y, pred_y):
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - pred_y))


model = TreeRNN(8, 1, 1, degree=2)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

root_emb = sess.run([model.final_state],
                    feed_dict={model.x: np.array([0, 1]), model.tree: np.array([[0, 1, 2]])})
emb, = sess.run([model.embeddings])
assert root_emb == 1 + emb[0] * emb[1]

out = sess.run([model.updates, model.loss],
               feed_dict={model.x: np.array([0, 1]),
                          model.tree: np.array([[0, 1, 2]]),
                          model.y: np.array([0])})
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug, maybe file issue on github so it could be triaged property?

Comment: Ok - will do.  Would you know any possible workarounds in the meantime?  It seems that the code can work without the while loop (writing the iterations out), so that may be one thing I can do.

Answer (score -1):

set parallel_iterations=1  in  tf.while_loop